# Moving the user after registering on the home .php page to the index .php page in Weatherpress

Tags: wordpress

When the user enters my site, he must log in first, and I put the user's login in home .php and I want to enter the index .php file when the user logs in. How can I do this in WeatherPress? It is a custom template.

I redirected the user to the index .php page, but it says that this page does not exist

Comment: Read about WP structure https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ . You want to redirect to specific page wp_safe_redirect( $url ); exit; https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.